# Bootstrap grid with different thumbnail height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="800x500.jpg" alt="">
             <div class="caption">
                  <h3>Image 800x500</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
</div> 
<div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="400x500.jpg" alt="">
             <div class="caption">
                  <h3>Image 400x500</h3>
             </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="400x500.jpg" alt="">
             <div class="caption">
                  <h3>Image 400x500</h3>
             </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="800x500.jpg" alt="">
             <div class="caption">
                  <h3>Image 800x500</h3>
             </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap and have the above grid with 2 images in each row. All images have the same width of 500px. The first image has a height of 800px, whereas the second has a height of 400px. The third image has a height of 400px and should appear directly under the first image. My problem is that the third image is not shown directly under the first. Is a big space between the first thumbnail and the third thumbnail. When each image has the same height it works. Any ideas why? Thank you

The desired result is:
http://wlog.cn/demo/waterfall/infinitescroll.html

Each image differ in height but is the same in width.

Comment: The problem is that your 4th img is 800 px tall therefore making your row 800 px tall. Since most imgs are vertically aligned on the bottom of the element it is leaving a big white space between img 1 and 3. I would reduce the height of the 4th image.

Comment: http://wlog.cn/demo/waterfall/infinitescroll.html This is the desired result where each image can differ in height.

Comment: From my understanding, the bootstrap grid is meant to be like that, to have rows. Have a look at http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose each row in a class="row"

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="800x500.jpg" alt="">
         <div class="caption">
              <h3>Image 800x500</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div> 
   <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="400x500.jpg" alt="">
         <div class="caption">
              <h3>Image 400x500</h3>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="400x500.jpg" alt="">
         <div class="caption">
              <h3>Image 400x500</h3>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="800x500.jpg" alt="">
         <div class="caption">
              <h3>Image 800x500</h3>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To get the precise kind of layout you linked to, you'll need to use something other than the Bootstrap grid system.  It doesn't work like that.